# Atualização (Insert) dinâmico com ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, atualização

Pesquisei e ainda não consegui resolver este problema.
é um evento onclick que envia uma requisição ao arquivo update.php, que faz um update na tabela notificações.
Segue código abaixo:

Aciona o evento onclick:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="'.$id.'">

<a onclick="sendData()" href="#">
```

Ajax dessa página:

```
<script>
function sendData()
{
    var id_n = $('#id').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"update.php",
        data: { id: id_n },
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(dta)
        {
            alert(dta);
        }

    });
}

</script>
```

Trecho do arquivo update.php, código:

```
$id = ($_POST['id']);
$sql = "UPDATE notif SET status = 1 WHERE id = :id";
$res = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$res->bindParam(':id',$id);
$res->execute();
$pdo->close();
```

O que pode estar errado?
Agradecido pela atenção.

Comment: Qual é o problema que te dá? O que é o `'#id'`? um `input`?

Comment: Ele não apresentava erro. Revi o código e removi "contentType:False"  "processData: False" e funcionou somente o método GET. O que pode estar errado pra funcionar o POST? O #id vem do value de um input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando passas um objeto como `{ id: id_n },` no `data` do ajax, o que o jQuery faz é converter em query string: `id=oValorDe_id_n` com o [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). Tendo a opção `processData: false` ele impede isso. Removendo ele assume `processData: true`.

Podes [ler mais sobre isso aqui](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server) (em Inglês)

Comment: Grato.
Mas ele só está passando via GET.

Outra coisa, como faço pra passar uma varíavel que varia por esse código?

tipo:

var id_n = $( <?php echo $id; ?> ).val();


tem jeito?


Agradeço

Comment: @AdrianoLeal daí a minha pergunta "O que é o `#id`".

Comment: É um input que é gerado por um laço.
São 8.
input type hidden id=idnot name=idnot value=$id